# iptables tool to measure latency instead of bandwidth

Tags: iptables, latency, iperf

I'm trying to measure the latency of having a lot of iptables rules.
I tried to use iperf but I think that bandwidth is not what i want.

Any help with this?

Comment: Why not use ping ?